# How can i make <li> span full width across <ul>?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, nav

I am creating a vertical navigation menu using ul and li I want to make

span the full width of ul so I can have underline for each menu item  (like this site (http://www.steffenallen.com/index.php))

However, there is a space in li that prevents it from spanning across the parent ul. Could someone tell me how the above website did it? Or, what I need to do?

```
<nav>
<ul class='menu'>
    <li class="menuItem">
        <a href="about.html"> About </a>                    
    </li>

    <li class="menuItem"> <a href="#"> Album     </a> 
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li class="submenu-Item"><a href="nepal.html">Nepal </a></li>
            <li class="submenu-Item"><a href="seattle.html">Seattle</a></li>
            <li class="submenu-Item"><a href="SouthKorea.html">South Korea</a></li>

        </ul>


    </li>
    <li class="menuItem"> <a href="#"> Contact </a> </li>
    <!-- <li>   </li> -->

</ul>
```

My CSS is

```
    ul,li{
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
}

ul.menu{
    width: 170px;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    /*width: 100%;*/
    /*margin-left: -20px;*/
    border: 1px solid orange;
}


ul.submenu{
    /*position: absolute;*/
    /*left: -999px;*/
    /*visibility: hidden;*/
    display: none;
}

li{
    width:140px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /*width:100%;*/
    border-left: 1px blue solid;
    border-right: 1px blue solid;
}

span{
    display: block;
}

li a, li span {
    /*width: 170px;*/
    /*width: 100%;*/
    border-bottom: #cbcbcb 1px solid;
}


li.menuItem, li.submenu-Item{
        text-align: right;
        margin: 1em 0em 1em 0em;
}
li.menuitem > a{
    color: #808080;
}

li a:hover{
    color: steelblue;
}

li.menuItem a.current{
    background-color: orange;
}

ul.menu:first-child{
    margin-top: 0

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First things first, your `CSS` is not well-written and hence a little difficult to understand.

The main problem in your code happens to be the default `CSS` that is being applied. You can remove that as follows:

```
ul, li {
   margin: 0; 
   padding: 0;
}
```

However, I'd suggest you simplify your `CSS` code as follows. This will still achieve what you are looking for all the while making your code more elegant and easily readable. Please see the code below :

```
ul, li {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
ul.menu {
    border: 1px solid Orange;
    width:200px;
}

ul.menu li {
    display:block;
    list-style-type:none;

}
ul.menu li a {
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    display:block;
    text-align:right;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.menu li ul {
    display:none;
}
ul.menu li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}

ul.menu li ul li:last-child {
    border-bottom:none;
}
```

See this working below :

```css
ul, li {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
ul.menu {
    border: 1px solid Orange;
    width:200px;
}

ul.menu li {
    display:block;
    list-style-type:none;
    
}
ul.menu li a {
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    display:block;
    text-align:right;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.menu li ul {
    display:none;
}
ul.menu li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}

ul.menu li ul li:last-child {
    border-bottom:none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul class='menu'>
        <li class="menuItem"> <a href="about.html"> About </a> 
        </li>
        <li class="menuItem"> <a href="#"> Album     </a> 
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li class="submenu-Item"><a href="nepal.html">Nepal </a>

                </li>
                <li class="submenu-Item"><a href="seattle.html">Seattle</a>

                </li>
                <li class="submenu-Item"><a href="SouthKorea.html">South Korea</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menuItem"> <a href="#"> Contact </a> 
        </li>
        <!-- <li>   </li> -->
    </ul>
```

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

On the left side there is the default margin/padding of `UL`s, so just remove that. It's 40px and depends on browser if margin or padding is used.

```
ul, li {margin-left: 0; padding-left: 0;}
```

The space on the right side is caused by your widths, list has 170px, items just 140px.

http://jsfiddle.net/8q9chvbh/